# Sending an image in a php POST request using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a POST request using cURL in PHP to eden ai to use their object detection API, and I'm getting a response saying:

> "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

I'm probably handling the file in a wrong way.

I also tried setting the full path of the image.

That's the function I'm using:

```
public function index() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = "https://api.edenai.run/v2/image/object_detection";
    $apiKey = "my_api_key";
    $imagePath = "/ise/myimage.jpg";
    
    $data = array(
        'providers' => 'api4ai, clarifai, amazon, google, microsoft, sentisight',
        'file' => $imagePath
    );
    
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput($response);

}
```

Comment: Handling file uploads is documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile

Comment: The heart of this question is how to send image data to EdenAI's object detection API specifically, but I'm having trouble coming up with a concise title edit to reflect that.

Comment: At the moment you aren't sending a valid URL as the file parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send file data as part of a JSON POST, that requires a `multipart/form-data` request.

According to the [EdenAI documentation](https://docs.edenai.co/reference/image_object_detection_create):

In order to use a JSON POST body for their API, you need to provide `file_url` instead, which is a publicly accessible URL for the image.

This is because when you use `application/json` as your HTTP POST content body, there isn't a standardized way to include the binary file data.

Alternatively, if exposing the image at a publicly accessible URL isn't tenable - don't use a JSON content body and instead use a regular CURL_POSTFIELDS form body. [Edit: And this is the case where you'd use `file` as the field to post the file data. Don't JSON-encode your POST fields and don't include the content-type header in your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option.] Relevant PHP documentation for uploading files this way and some examples can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile (This is also a common question on stack overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You must to change your code to this :

````
public function index() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "https://api.edenai.run/v2/image/object_detection";
    $apiKey = "my_api_key";
    $imagePath = "/ise/myimage.jpg";
    
    $data = array(
        'providers' => 'api4ai, clarifai, amazon, google, microsoft, sentisight',
        'file' => new CURLFile($imagePath, mime_content_type($imagePath), basename($imagePath))
    );
    
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput($response);

}```new CURLFile($imagePath, mime_content_type($imagePath), basename($imagePath))
````